# Android Studio SQLite error that no column in database named name.Please Help I am stuck with this error

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

[This is the error which I am getting via Android studio.Please help...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpVaz.png)

[Here it contains the Line 47 from where the error is started .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZggmC.png)

[This is the addContact method in my DataBaseHandler.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3Bgu.png)

[This is the oncreate Method of DataBaseHandler where you can also check the query .  Please Help....

][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb3Qx.png)

If above Images are not available, You can refer to these code samples.

THis is the error I am receiving while running my app

```
    E/SQLiteLog: (1) table contacts_table has no column named name
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting phone_number=9090909090 name=Harry
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts_table has no column named name (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts_table(phone_number,name) VALUES (?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:988)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:593)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1597)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1468)
        at com.example.dbdemo.data.MyDbHandler.addContact(MyDbHandler.java:52)
        at com.example.dbdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7873)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7862)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3277)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3441)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2045)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7405)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:502)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

This is my onCreate method of dataBaseHandler class in which you can see the query to create table. I can't understand that why it is showing that name column is not created while I have created it.
Here's the code....

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + Params.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + Params.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + Params.KEY_NAME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + Params.KEY_PHONE + " TEXT NOT NULL);" ;

    Log.d("dbjarvis", "Query being run is : "+ createTable);

    db.execSQL(createTable);

    Log.d("dbjarvis","succesfully executed database  query.");
}
```

Now here a code sample where I made contacts and add them...

```
 // Creating a contact object for the db
    Contact harry = new Contact();
    harry.setPhoneNumber("9090909090");
    harry.setName("Harry");

    Contact deepanshu = new Contact();
    deepanshu.setName("Deepanshu");
    deepanshu.setPhoneNumber("89903249069");

    // Adding a contact to the db
    db.addContact(harry);
    db.addContact(deepanshu);
```

Now here's the last code sample of addContact method of my dataBaseHandler class. Please check it also.
Here's the code...

```
 public void addContact(Contact contact){
    Log.d("dbjarvis","addContact method is started running.");
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Params.KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(Params.KEY_PHONE, contact.getPhoneNumber());


    db.insert(Params.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    Log.d("dbharry", values+" Successfully inserted");
    db.close();
    Log.d("dbjarvis","addContact method is finished here .");

}
```

Every thing just ended ...Please help me ..
I am stuck with this from 4-5 days  and I have tried a lots of methods but not a single one work.
Please Help me :(

Comment: Have you ever changed the schema of your database? If so did you increment the version number?

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of column not found is a mis-understanding of when the database handler **onCreate** method runs.

The **onCreate** method runs once for the lifetime of the database rather than every time the App is run.

If changes are made to the database schema then you need to either delete the database or apply the changes via suitable code in the **onUpgrade** method in conjunction with an increase in the version number passed to the SQLiteOpenHelper (typically the 4th parameter passed in the super call).

I prefer to delete the database BUT any existing data will be lost. Deleting the database  can be done via Device Explorer (if access allows) or by uninstalling the App.

Once the App has been uninstalled you can just rerun the App and assuming the new/changed SQL invoked is sound then the table(s) will be created.

If you have data that you need to keep then perhaps the simplest way is to utilise the **onUpgrade** method using ALTER TABLE SQL (IF that will do what is required) in line with  increasing the version number.

Comment: Thank you soo much ... I have deleted the whole app and made it from the beginning, and it worked.